# Ajax form not submitting

Tags: ajax, forms

I followed the [Submit Ajax Form tutorial on tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) ,
but cannot figure out for the life of me why my data won't have addreply.php applied to it. When I look in my mysql table, the data does not get inserted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I searched the web and have troubleshooted for many hours.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".replyLink").one("click", function(){
$(this).parent().after("<div id='contact_form'></div>");
$("#contact_form").append("<form id='replyForm'></form>");
$("#replyForm").append("<input class='enterName' id='enterName' type='text' 
name='name' placeholder='name' rows='1' cols='20' />");
$("#replyForm").append("<textarea class='enterReply' id='enterReply' name='comment'  
placeholder='reply'></textarea>");
$("#replyForm").append("<input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>");

commentID= $(this).parent().attr('id');

$("#replyForm").append("<input class='replyButton' id='replyButton' type='submit' `value='reply'/>");`
$(".enterReply").slideDown();                                   

$(".replyButton").slideDown();

});

$(".replyButton").click(function() {

var name = $("input#enterName").val();
var reply = $("textarea#enterReply").val();



var dataString = 'name='+ name.val() + '&comment=' + reply.val();  

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "addreply.php",  
data: dataString,  
success: function() {  
}  
});  
return false;
});

**addreply.php**

<?php
session_start();

$replyID= $_POST['id'];

$name= $_POST['name'];
$comment= $_POST['comment'];
$type= $_POST['type'];
$song= $_POST['song'];

if($song == ''){
$song= 'not';
}

include 'connection.php';

if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == 'yes') {
$query1= "INSERT INTO ApprovedComments(name, comment, Authorized, type, reply_ID, song, date)
VALUES('$name', '$comment', 'YES', '$type', '$replyID', '$song', NOW());";

$insertComment= mysql_query($query1);
// echo "hi";
}

if( !isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) ) {
$query2= "INSERT INTO PreApprovedComments(name, comment, reply_ID, song, date)
VALUES('$name', '$comment', '$replyID', '$song', NOW());";      

$insertComment= mysql_query($query2);
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: check in firebug..areu getting any error on console?Check on net tab is ur request getting submitted to the server? Last but not least I hope you have added jquery library in ur HTML..

Comment: thanks for responding. i checked all those things. its most likely not one of those really simple mistakes. after i hit the reply button, the page refreshes and redirects me to (website_name)/?name=sss&comment=sss&id=   . Don't know why that info is showing up in url

Comment: post ur HTML code for reply button..On button click page shouldnot refresh..because I can see return false statement is already added on click event..if the page is getting refreshed then there must be some error shown in console in firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "addreply.php",  
    data: $("#replyForm").serialize()+'name='+ encodeURIComponent(name) + 
          '&comment=' + encodeURIComponent(reply),  
    success: function() {  
    }  
});
```

this will post all the fields in the `#replyForm` form and the name and comment fields.

Comment: thanks for the reply. didn't work though. this is really strange.

Comment: @user1940631 remove `var dataString = 'name='+ name.val() + '&comment=' + reply.val();`  this is causing an error causing your form to submit(name is a string and has no method val()).